# Using promises with Ember

Tags: javascript, ember.js, promise

I'm struggling to chain promises in an Ember controller.

To illustrate I've made an example of the issue on [JSBIN here](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/IDoKAZe/1/embed?html,js,console,output)

Also included the Ember code here:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  result_of_request: 'nothing',

  first_request: function() {

    // create a promise which is immediately resolved
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      resolve("first resolved");
    });

    // once the promise has resolved it should call the next function?
    promise.then(function(data) {
      // does log the data (has resolved)...
      console.log("data is : " + data);

      // but neither this
      this.set("result_of_request", "first");

      // nor this work
      second_request();
    }); 
  }.property(),

   second_request: function() {
    console.log("second request");
  }.property()

});
```

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: `this` is not the Controller inside the callback, and `second_request` is a method (property) not a function (variable).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are two problems, first `this` is not available inside the promise callback because it's async, this means the time the promise is resolved `this` no more refers to the controller, so you need to store the value beforehand somewhere, as you can see we store it in a var called `self`. And second the `.property()` on your second function should also be removed because it's not needed as far I can see. Furthermore you should use `.send([methodname])` instead of invoking the controller methods directly or using the *dot notation*.

This leaves us with this modifications making your example work:

```
App.IndexController = Ember.Controller.extend({
  result_of_request: 'nothing',

  first_request: function() {
    var self = this;

    // create a promise which is immediately resolved
    var promise = new Ember.RSVP.Promise(function(resolve, reject){
      resolve("first resolved");
    });

    // once the promise has resolved it should call the next function?
    promise.then(function(data) {
      // does log the data (has resolved)...
      console.log("data is : " + data);

      self.set("result_of_request", "first");

      self.send("second_request");
    }); 
  }.property(),

   second_request: function() {
    console.log("second request");
    console.log(this.get("result_of_request"));
  }

});
```

The above code yields this console output:

```
"data is : first resolved"
"second request"
"first"
```

And here your working [jsbin](http://emberjs.jsbin.com/ArONiLa/3/edit).

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you, this is a really clear answer and explanation. In the end self.send did not work well for me when trying to chain together several promises & I ended up using a self.get with a computed property to return the promise. Just thought I'd mention this for anyone trying the same thing.